# Is there a way to create hashmap in javascript and manipulate it like adding and deleting values

Tags: javascript, hashmap, keyvaluepair

My requirement is to store key-value pairs in a data structure and fetch or delete the pairs when necessary using keys in JavaScript.

How can I do it in JavaScript as one does it in Java?

I have seen an answer creating an instance of hash map like:

```
var hash={};
```

Now Ie can add values in it like:

```
hash={ "January":"1","Feb":"2" }
```

Can I insert values dynamically using keys and fetch them and also get the size of the hash map?

Comment: And how is this Java?

Comment: What have you tried? You should be able to Google "javascript objects" or "javascript map" or "javascript associate array" and see all the information you need.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, that's an associative array (`var hash = new Object();`)

```
//You can add in these ways:

hash.January='1';
hash['Feb']='2';

//For length:
console.log(Object.keys(hash).length)

//To fetch by key:
console.log(hash['Feb']) // '2'

//To fetch all:
for(var key in hash){
    console.log('key is :' + key + ' and value is : '+ hash[key])
}
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use the built-in Map object.

```
var myMap = new Map();
var keyObj = {};
myMap.set(keyObj, "value");
myMap.get(keyObj); 

for (var [key, value] of myMap) {
  console.log(key + " = " + value);
}
```

More information here : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Map

Comment: English link for whoever wants it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Answer (score 1):

`hash["dynamic"] = 5` will insert something. `Object.keys(hash).length` will get the size.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this guide on JavaScript Objects:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

JavaScript objects can be accessed in a number of ways. Let's take this object as an example:

```
var person = {
  first_name: "John",
  last_name: "Smith",
  age: 39
};
```

If you wished to access the first_name you could do:

```
person.first_name;
```

Or

```
person['first_name'];
```

These would both retrieve the value.

You may also set the value in similar fashion:

```
person.first_name = "Michael";
```

Now, if you were referring to creating an iterator using a keys() method like in Java then you can't do that exactly, but you can do something similar.

You can iterate over the object however in a similar manner that you would iterate over an array:

```
for (var property in object) {
  if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
    // do stuff
  }
```

}

A newer built-in is also available where you can use Object.keys(person) to get an array of the objects keys. Read more here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

I suggest using Google a little more. There are plenty of resources out there for this type of question. You would find the answer more quickly than someone would respond on here.

Comment: No need to use `object.hasOwnProperty()` anymore if you create your map with `Object.create(null)`.  This creates a prototype-less object so it contains no properties other than what you put into it.  I think this is new with ECMAScript 5?

Answer (score 1):

elegant and simple [javascript hashmap code](https://github.com/Abin-Kuriakose/hashmap-javascript)

```
var hashMap=function(){
this.hashDict={};//dictionary
this.size=0;
this.debug=true;
return this;
}
```

now to insert :

```
hashMap.prototype.put=function(_key,_value){
if (!this.hashDict.hasOwnProperty(_key)) {
this.hashDict[_key] = _value;
++this.size;
}
else if(this.debug)
throw 'duplicate keys not allowed. key : '+_key;
}
```

you can also get the size using and perform all other manipulations

only you have to do is create the object of class hash map like :

```
hashmap n = new hashMap();
n.put('key','value');
n.get('key');
n.size; // gives size
```